# SDK Location not found Parse projects

Tags: android-studio, parse-platform, import, gradle

I am trying to import a Parse sample project in to android studio.
I already have lot of projects which I have created from scratch and also import few other projects which I downloaded from github. But when I downloaded the Parse website's To-Do list project and open it, I am getting 
SDK Location not found.

Any other special settings that I need to take note of?
Also at first I tot that may be the min version for the project might be some SDK which I don't have so I changed it in Manifest file to the one I have, still the same error. Tks for your inputs
[image]